# C substrings / C string slicing?

Tags: c

Hy everybody!
I am trying to write a program that checks if a given string of text is a palindrome (for this I made a function called is_palindrome that works) and if any of it's substrings is a palindrome, and I can't figure out what is the optimal way to do this:

For example, for the string s = "abcdefg" it should first check "a", then "ab", "abc", "abcd" and so on, for each character

```
In Python this is the equivalent of
s[:1], s[:2], ...      (a, ab, ...)
s[1:2], s[1:3] ...     (b, bc, ...)
```

What function/method is there that I can use in a similar way in C ?

Comment: If you don't want to (or can't) change the source string you'll need to make copies of each substring, e.g. using [strndup(s+start,length)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strndup) if you're on Linux. Do you need to extract substrings? Can you just compare sequences of characters in-place?

Comment: C isn't the language I'd pick for fancy string handling. You'll have to index all the substrings manually.

Comment: Your function can just return the value of "the string is not empty"; *every* non-empty string has a substring that is a palindrome (since any length-1 substring will do).

Answer (score 15):

You can use [strncpy](https://devdocs.io/c/string/byte/strncpy) to get a slice of your "string"

```
void slice(const char* str, char* result, size_t start, size_t end) {
    strncpy(result, str + start, end - start);
}
```

Exemple usage where I want to skip the first 5 characters and get following 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void slice(const char* str, char* result, size_t start, size_t end) {
    strncpy(result, str + start, end - start);
}

int main() {
    const char* foo = "Hey, Hello world";
    printf("%s\n", foo);

    char slicedFoo[5] = "";
    slice(foo, slicedFoo, 5, 5 + 4);
    printf("%s\n", slicedFoo);
}
```

Outputs

```
Hey, Hello world
Hell
```

Comment: end is inclusive or exclusive?

Answer (score 10):

This `slice_str()` function will do the trick, with `end` actually being the end character, rather than one-past-the-end as in Python slicing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void slice_str(const char * str, char * buffer, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    for ( size_t i = start; i <= end; ++i ) {
        buffer[j++] = str[i];
    }
    buffer[j] = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    const char * str = "Polly";
    const size_t len = strlen(str);
    char buffer[len + 1];

    for ( size_t start = 0; start < len; ++start ) {
        for ( int end = len - 1; end >= (int) start; --end ) {
            slice_str(str, buffer, start, end);
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which, when used from the above `main()` function, outputs:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./allsubstr
Polly
Poll
Pol
Po
P
olly
oll
ol
o
lly
ll
l
ly
l
y
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

Answer (score 7):

There isn't; you'll have to write your own.

Answer (score 2):

In order to check a string, you would need to supply to the number of characters to check in order to check for a palindrome:

```
int palindrome(char* str, int len)
{
  if (len < 2 )
  {
    return 0;
  }
  // position p and q on the first and last character
  char* p = str; 
  char* q = str + len - 1;
  // compare start char with end char
  for ( ; p < str + len / 2; ++p, --q )
  {
    if (*p != *q) 
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

now you would need to call the function above for each substring (as you described it, i.e. always starting from the beginning) e.g.

```
 char candidate[] = "wasitaratisaw";
 for (int len = 0; len < strlen(candidate); ++len)
 { 
    if (palindrome(candidate, len))
    {
    ...
    }
 }
```

disclaimer: not compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you don't need a string slicing function just to check for palindromes within substrings:

```
/* start: Pointer to first character in the string to check.
 * end: Pointer to one byte beyond the last character to check.
 *
 * Return:
 *   -1 if start >= end; this is considered an error
 *    0 if the substring is not a palindrome
 *    1 if the substring is a palindrome
 */
int
ispalin (const char *start, const char *end)
{
  if (start >= end)
    return -1;

  for (; start < end; ++start)
    if (*start != *--end)
      return 0;

  return 1;
}
```

With that, you can create the following:

```
int
main ()
{
  const char *s = "madam";

  /* i: index of first character in substring
   * n: number of characters in substring
   */
  size_t i, n;

  size_t len = strlen (s);

  for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
      for (n = 1; n <= len - i; ++n)
        {
          /* Start of substring. */
          const char *start = s + i;

          /* ispalin(s[i:i+n]) in Python */
          switch (ispalin (start, start + n))
            {
            case -1:
              fprintf (stderr, "error: %p >= %p\n", (void *) start, (void *) (start + n));
              break;
            case 0:
              printf ("Not a palindrome: %.*s\n", (int) n, start);
              break;
            case 1:
              printf ("Palindrome: %.*s\n", (int) n, start);
              break;
            } /* switch (ispalin) */
        } /* for (n) */
    } /* for (i) */
}
```

Of course, if you really wanted a string slicing function merely for output (since you technically shouldn't cast a `size_t` to `int`), and you still want to be able to format the output easily, the answer by [Paul Griffiths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26620524/539810) should suffice quite well, or you can use mine or even one of `strncpy` or the nonstandard `strlcpy`, though they all have their strengths and weaknesses:

```
/* dest must have
 *     1 + min(strlen(src), n)
 * bytes available and must not overlap with src.
 */
char *
strslice (char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
{
  char *destp = dest;

  /* memcpy here would be ideal, but that would mean walking the string twice:
   * once by calling strlen to determine the minimum number of bytes to copy
   * and once for actually copying the substring.
   */
  for (; n != 0 && *src != 0; --n)
    *destp++ = *src++;

  *destp = 0;

  return dest;
}
```

`strslice` actually works like a combination of `strncpy` and the nonstandard `strlcpy`, though there are differences between these three functions:

- `strlcpy` will cut the copied string short to add a null terminator at `dest[n - 1]`, so copying exactly `n` bytes before adding a null terminator requires you to pass `n + 1` as the buffer size.
- `strncpy` may not terminate the string at all, leaving `dest[n - 1]` equal to `src[n - 1]`, so you would need to add a null terminator yourself just in case. If `n` is greater than the `src` string length, `dest` will be padded with null terminators until `n` bytes have been written.
- `strslice` will copy up to `n` bytes if necessary, like `strncpy`, and will require an extra byte for the null terminator, meaning a maximum of `n+1` bytes are necessary. It doesn't waste time writing unnecessary null terminators as `strncpy` does. This can be thought of as a "lightweight `strlcpy`" with a small difference in what `n` means and can be used where the resulting string length won't matter.

You could also create a `memslice` function if you wanted, which would allow for embedded null bytes, but it already exists as `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any built-in function/method in any standard C library which can handle this. However, you can come up with your own method to do the same.